# UPDATE/INSERT statement within an IF statement within a LOOP using sequence

Tags: sql, oracle, loops, if-statement, plsql

```
CURSOR text IS
SELECT *
FROM DATA

CURSOR MATCHES IS
SELECT NAME
FROM DATA
INTERSECT
SELECT DESCRIPTION
FROM my_table



BEGIN
FOR i IN text

OPEN MATCHES
FETCH MATCHES INTO MATCH
CLOSE MATCH

IF i IN MATCH
THEN
UPDATE my_table
SET col1 = correlating_new_column1, col2 = correlating_new_column2, col3 = correlating_new_column3
WHERE table_im_trying_to_populate.code = my_seq.curval
ELSE
INSERT INTO TABLE_IM_TRYING_TO_POPULATE(CODE, NAME, DESCRIPTION, col1, col2, col3)
VALUES(my_seq.nextval, other_name, other_description, correlating_new_column1, correlating_new_column2, correlating_new_column3)
END IF;
END LOOP;
```

Basically I am trying to take an explicit cursor I made that is a select statement of a table and then do a line by line loop of that and put it into my other existing table. If it comes across a name in my other exisiting table it will update some of the columns. Else it inserts the whole record into that table. I am attempting to use sequence to update the 'code' column so that it updates where the code from the other existing table = my_seq.curval. Then for the inset it just goes to the next val. I know this is complicated but Im really just trying to see if I have the setup correct. Just started using sql developer for oracle not to long ago.

Comment: You're trying to insert into/update the same table, based on rows from a different table? You forgot to include your cursor declaration in your example code; it would help if you could update your question to include that.

Comment: Yes update/insert into the same already existing table. If the names match for a row I update some columns. If there is no match meaning no record for that name then I insert a whole new record into table with a new code number.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a huge number of problems with your code. However, it looks like what you're trying to do can be achieved with a single `MERGE` statement, along the lines of:

```
merge into table_im_trying_to_populate tgt
using data_table src
  on (tgt.name = src.other_name
      and tgt.description = src.other_description)
when matched then
  update set tgt.col1 = src.correlating_new_column1,
             tgt.col2 = src.correlating_new_column2,
             tgt.col3 = src.correlating_new_column3
when not matched then
  insert (tgt.code, tgt.name, tgt.description, tgt.col1, tgt.col2, tgt.col3)
  values (my_seq.nextval, src.other_name, src.other_description, src.correlating_new_column1, src.correlating_new_column2, src.correlating_new_column3);
```

This assumes that the other_name and other_description columns in the data table is unique. I've also had to guess at what the join condition should be, since the join condition you had in your example update statement (`table_im_trying_to_populate.code = my_seq.currval`) didn't make any sense - you don't use currval to join against as a general rule, since it isn't populated unless you've previously pulled a value from the sequence in the same session.

If this doesn't match what you're trying to do, please update your question with some sample data in both tables and the expected output, and we should be able to help you further.

Comment: If I used this merge method would I use my cursors for the things I am merging or would I just create my select statements for them?                                   Talking about this part                                                                           merge into table_im_trying_to_populate tgt
using data_table src

Comment: Are you saying that there's only a subset of data from your source table that you want to merge into your target table? If so, you could do `... using (select ... from ... where ...) src`

Comment: If I was to encapsulate this into a procedure would I need anything else besides a create procedure, begin and end statement?

Comment: Nope! Once you verify the merge is working as expected, you can just plonk it into the proc.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help! Newbie over here haha

Comment: Not a problem *{:-)